# How to call async functions from a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm exporting a Firebase cloud function that I can call from my iOS app.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((someData, context) => {

});
```

How do I call an async function?

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((someData, context) => {

    return await someAsyncFunction();

});
```

The documentation states to return a promise but I'm not sure how to wrap an existing async function into a promise that I can return.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

> To return data after an asynchronous operation, return a promise. The
> data returned by the promise is sent back to the client. For example,
> you could return sanitized text that the callable function wrote to
> the Realtime Database:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try appending async in front of function to use await.

```js
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall(async(someData, context) => {

  return await someAsyncFunction();

});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either make the callback function passed on `onCall` async so you can use await inside it:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (someData, context) => {
    return await someAsyncFunction();
});
```

Or, you can simply return the promise returned by `someAsyncFunction`:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall((someData, context) => {
    return someAsyncFunction();
});
```

In either case, you are obliged to *return a promise* that resolves with the data to serialize and send to the client app.  Both of these methods will do that.